# Cant find module even though its installed and can run

Tags: python, linux, pip, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I've looked into Python's speech recognition and it's working great so far.
It offers a wide range of software, but I'll be using `CMUSphinx`, since it works offline.
`CMUSphinx` is installed and working correctly when started through their own program `cmupshinx_continous`. But when trying to write my own Python-script, it cannot find the module `speech_recognition`. This is odd because when I run:

```
python -m speech_recognition
```

it works perfectly fine. But when I start my script:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

    # obtain audio from the microphone
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    # recognize speech using Sphinx
    try:
        print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

I get the error message that the module: `speech_recognition` cannot be found.
When using

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

I first used `sudo pip install` but when it didn't work I thought it might have been because I installed it in root. So I uninstalled it and used `pip install --user SpeechRecognition` instead to no avail.
I also tried adding something with `PYTHONPATH`, but I have no idea what I tried to do.

So right now I'm very stuck. Please keep in mind that I'm incredibly new to both Linux and Python.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: How do you execute your script?

Comment: Try typing `>>> import speech_recognition as sr` in the terminal first.

Comment: @syntonym I write the code in python3 IDLE and execute it.

Comment: @GaneshK Writing import speech_recognition as sr in the terminal gives no error message, so that should be correct. Right?

Comment: IDLE is using a different python version than the one you use when you type `python`. Either change IDLE to the terminal version or find out which python version IDLE uses and use that (probably `python3`). Alternativly just ditch IDLE and execute your script via `python myscript.py`.

Comment: @syntonym Oh my, thank you so much!! When executed through terminal with python myscript.py it worked like a charm. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it as the solution. You really made this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost always when you can access a module from one point but not another (think of script/program, terminal/editor, ...) you have multiple python versions and only installed the module in one of them.

In your case IDLE uses a different python version than you on the terminal. You have multiple possibilities:

- configure IDLE to use the version you use on the terminal
- use the version that IDLE uses (and install all modules again)
- don't use IDLE to run your scripts, instead use `python myscript.py`

You mentioned that IDLE is python3, normally in the terminal `python` is python2. You can try `python --version` to show which version of python you use. `python3` might be the python you use in IDLE, the pip would probably be `pip3`.

Because the library does support python3 I would advise to use python3 instead of python2.

IDLE unfortunately isn't that great of an editor, I recommend something else like notepad++, pycharm, vim or emacs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package is installed in some other version of python.

Try typing `sudo python -m pip install SpeechRecognition`

It worked for me. If not the best thing to do would be:

1. Go to the [repo](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition)
2. Clone it
3. Install it

Try the first method before moving on.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it doesn't work either. I don't think the problem is whether SpeechRecognition is properly installed or not since it works in the terminal.